# Tiny PE на Windows 10

Tags: windows, ассемблер, fasm, pe

мои очумелые ручки добрались до самого маленького исполняемого файла и нашли на просторах сети аж 268-ми байтный пример для Win7x64. Но вот на моей Win10x64 не работает, когда смотрю в отладчике, ловлю исключение ACCESS_VIOLATION, а потом оказалось, что User32 не загружена. По переставлял всё, попробовал добавлять ".dll" и в верхнем регистре писал, указатели местами менял, нулевые элементы добавлял - ничего не помогает. Так вот вопрос, не изменилось ли на 10-ке какая-нибудь важная деталь? Может есть рабочие примеры? а может это вообще даже на 7-ке не запускается?

```
format binary as 'exe'

IMAGE_DOS_SIGNATURE             equ 5A4Dh
IMAGE_NT_SIGNATURE              equ 00004550h
PROCESSOR_AMD_X8664             equ 8664h
IMAGE_SCN_CNT_CODE              equ 00000020h
IMAGE_SCN_MEM_READ              equ 40000000h
IMAGE_SCN_MEM_WRITE             equ 80000000h
IMAGE_SCN_CNT_INITIALIZED_DATA  equ 00000040h
IMAGE_SUBSYSTEM_WINDOWS_GUI     equ 2
IMAGE_NT_OPTIONAL_HDR64_MAGIC   equ 20Bh
IMAGE_FILE_RELOCS_STRIPPED      equ 1
IMAGE_FILE_EXECUTABLE_IMAGE     equ 2
IMAGE_DLLCHARACTERISTICS_TERMINAL_SERVER_AWARE equ 8000h

include 'win64a.inc'
org 0
use64
IMAGE_BASE = 400000h
Signature:              dw IMAGE_DOS_SIGNATURE,0
ntHeader                dd IMAGE_NT_SIGNATURE;'PE'
;image_header--------------------------
.Machine                dw PROCESSOR_AMD_X8664
.Count_of_section       dw 0;2
.TimeStump              dd 0
.Symbol_table_offset    dd 0;ntHeader
.Symbol_table_count     dd 0
.Size_of_optional_header dw EntryPoint-optional_header
.Characteristics        dw 0x20 or IMAGE_FILE_RELOCS_STRIPPED or 
IMAGE_FILE_EXECUTABLE_IMAGE
;20h Handle >2Gb addresses
;-------------------------------------
optional_header:
.Magic_optional_header  dw IMAGE_NT_OPTIONAL_HDR64_MAGIC
.Linker_version_major_and_minor dw 9 
.Size_of_code           dd 0
.Size_of_init_data      dd 0;xC0
.Size_of_uninit_data    dd 0
.entry_point            dd EntryPoint
.base_of_code           dd ntHeader
.image_base             dq IMAGE_BASE
.section_alignment      dd 4
.file_alignment         dd 4
.OS_version_major_minor dw 5,2
.image_version_major_minor dd 0
.subsystem_version_major_minor dw 5,2
.Win32_version          dd 0
.size_of_image          dd EndOfImage
.size_of_header         dd EntryPoint
.checksum               dd 0
.subsystem              dw IMAGE_SUBSYSTEM_WINDOWS_GUI
.DLL_flag               dw IMAGE_DLLCHARACTERISTICS_TERMINAL_SERVER_AWARE
.Stack_allocation       dq 0x100000
.Stack_commit           dq 0x1000
.Heap_allocation        dq 0x100000
.Heap_commit            dq 0x1000
.loader_flag            dd 0
.number_of_dirs         dd (EntryPoint-export_RVA_size)/8
export_RVA_size        dq 0
.import_RVA             dd import_
.import_size            dd end_import-import_
;------------------------------------------------
EntryPoint:
   enter 20h,0        ; space for 4 arguments + 16byte aligned stack
   xor ecx, ecx                   ; 1. argument: rcx = hWnd = NULL
   mov r9, rcx                    ; 4. argument: r9d = uType = MB_OK = 0
   mov edx,MsgCaption+IMAGE_BASE  ; 2. argument: edx = window text
   mov r8,rdx                     ; 3. argument: r8  = caption
   call [MessageBox]
   leave
   ret
;------------------------------------------------
MsgCaption      db "Iczelion's tutorial #2a",0
;-------------------------------------------------
Import_Table:
user32_table:
MessageBox  dq _MessageBox
import_:
dd 0,0,0,user32_dll,user32_table
dd 0
user32_dll    db "user32",0,0
dw 0
_MessageBox     db 0,0,"MessageBoxA"
end_import:
times 268-end_import db 0  ;filling up to 268 bytes
EndOfImage:
```

компилирую в fasm'е
ну и бинарник http://dropmefiles.com/ol4m7

Comment: " а может это вообще даже на 7-ке не запускается?" занят какой-то гикотой, а банально VM или VPS по 300 руб пользоваться не умеет

Comment: @Rou1997 странное замечание, и уж тем более выводы. 1)Вопрос не стоял в проверки многоплатформенности, а скорее наоборот. 2)Это уточнение заранее отвечает на вопросы по типу - а на самой семёрке пробовали? Потому как автору не верить причин нет, но и гарантий не даю. 3) запуск VM удобен, когда виртуалка под рукой, а устанавливать ради сомнительного теста - нецелесообразно, про VPS вообще молчу. 4)Любая банальность перебивается ленью на раз. p.s. лично мне, когда нужна другая ОС,просто переустанавливаю основную, благо занимает от силы час, а всё необходимое вмещается на внешний 4'х терабайтник.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Судя по всему win10 не принимает файлы с нулевым количеством секций. Точнее не подгружает к ним dll из таблицы импорта. Достаточно добавить одну общую секцию и задать количество секций больше нуля, так всё сразу заработало. Более того, там где я брал исходники, было написано, что файлы меньше 268'ми байт не читаются, однако удалив текст сообщения и задав адрес названия секции(".code ") вместо него, программа запустилась и вывела сообщение, хотя получилось 247 байт.

FASM:

```
format binary as 'exe'
IMAGE_DOS_SIGNATURE     equ 5A4Dh
IMAGE_NT_SIGNATURE      equ 00004550h
PROCESSOR_AMD_X8664     equ 8664h
IMAGE_SCN_CNT_CODE      equ 00000020h
IMAGE_SCN_MEM_READ      equ 40000000h
IMAGE_SCN_MEM_WRITE     equ 80000000h
IMAGE_SCN_CNT_INITIALIZED_DATA  equ 00000040h
IMAGE_SUBSYSTEM_WINDOWS_GUI equ 2
IMAGE_NT_OPTIONAL_HDR64_MAGIC   equ 20Bh
IMAGE_FILE_RELOCS_STRIPPED  equ 1
IMAGE_FILE_EXECUTABLE_IMAGE equ 2
IMAGE_DLLCHARACTERISTICS_TERMINAL_SERVER_AWARE equ 8000h
include 'win64a.inc'
org 0
use64
IMAGE_BASE = 400000h
Signature:      dw IMAGE_DOS_SIGNATURE,0
ntHeader        dd IMAGE_NT_SIGNATURE;'PE'
;image_header--------------------------
.Machine        dw PROCESSOR_AMD_X8664
.Count_of_section   dw 1;2
.TimeStump      dd 0
.Symbol_table_offset    dd 0;ntHeader
.Symbol_table_count dd 0
.Size_of_optional_header dw section_table-optional_header
.Characteristics    dw 0x20 or IMAGE_FILE_RELOCS_STRIPPED or\
IMAGE_FILE_EXECUTABLE_IMAGE
;20h Handle >2Gb addresses
;-------------------------------------
optional_header:
.Magic_optional_header  dw IMAGE_NT_OPTIONAL_HDR64_MAGIC
.Linker_version_major_and_minor dw 9
.Size_of_code       dd 0
.Size_of_init_data  dd 0;xC0
.Size_of_uninit_data    dd 0
.entry_point        dd EntryPoint
.base_of_code       dd ntHeader
.image_base     dq IMAGE_BASE
.section_alignment  dd 4
.file_alignment     dd 4
.OS_version_major_minor dw 5,2
.image_version_major_minor dd 0
.subsystem_version_major_minor dw 5,2
.Win32_version      dd 0
.size_of_image      dd end_import
.size_of_header     dd section_table
.checksum       dd 0
.subsystem      dw IMAGE_SUBSYSTEM_WINDOWS_GUI
.DLL_flag       dw IMAGE_DLLCHARACTERISTICS_TERMINAL_SERVER_AWARE
.Stack_allocation   dq 0x100000
.Stack_commit       dq 0x1000
.Heap_allocation    dq 0x100000
.Heap_commit        dq 0x1000
.loader_flag        dd 0
.number_of_dirs     dd (section_table-export_RVA_size)/8
export_RVA_size        dq 0
.import_RVA     dd import_
.import_size        dd end_import-import_
;------------------------------------------------
section_table        dq '.text'
.virtual_size        dd end_import-EntryPoint
.virtual_address    dd EntryPoint
.Physical_size       dd end_import-EntryPoint
.Physical_offset    dd EntryPoint
.Relocations_and_Linenumbers dq 0
.Relocations_and_Linenumbers_count dd 0
.Attributes    dd IMAGE_SCN_MEM_WRITE or IMAGE_SCN_CNT_CODE or IMAGE_SCN_MEM_READ or IMAGE_SCN_CNT_INITIALIZED_DATA
;--------данные, код и импорт-----------------------------------------
EntryPoint:
   enter 20h,0        ; space for 4 arguments + 16byte aligned stack
   xor ecx, ecx           ; 1. argument: rcx = hWnd = NULL
   mov r9, rcx            ; 4. argument: r9d = uType = MB_OK = 0
   mov edx,section_table+IMAGE_BASE  ; 2. argument: edx = window text
   mov r8,rdx             ; 3. argument: r8  = caption
   call [MessageBox]
   leave
   ret
Import_Table:
user32_table:
MessageBox  dq _MessageBox
import_:
dd 0,0,0,user32_dll,user32_table
dd 0
user32_dll    db "user32",0,0
dw 0
_MessageBox db 0,0,"MessageBoxA"
end_import:
;times 268-end_import db 0  ;filling up to 268 bytes
EndOfImage:
```

А если всё-таки без секций, то доступна Kernel32, KernelBase, ntdll

```
format binary as 'exe'
IMAGE_DOS_SIGNATURE     equ 5A4Dh
IMAGE_NT_SIGNATURE      equ 00004550h
PROCESSOR_AMD_X8664     equ 8664h
IMAGE_SCN_CNT_CODE      equ 00000020h
IMAGE_SCN_MEM_READ      equ 40000000h
IMAGE_SCN_MEM_WRITE     equ 80000000h
IMAGE_SCN_CNT_INITIALIZED_DATA  equ 00000040h
IMAGE_SUBSYSTEM_WINDOWS_GUI equ 2
IMAGE_NT_OPTIONAL_HDR64_MAGIC   equ 20Bh
IMAGE_FILE_RELOCS_STRIPPED  equ 1
IMAGE_FILE_EXECUTABLE_IMAGE equ 2
IMAGE_DLLCHARACTERISTICS_TERMINAL_SERVER_AWARE equ 8000h
include 'win64a.inc'
org 0
use64
IMAGE_BASE = 400000h
Signature:      dw IMAGE_DOS_SIGNATURE,0
ntHeader        dd IMAGE_NT_SIGNATURE;'PE'
;image_header--------------------------
.Machine        dw PROCESSOR_AMD_X8664
.Count_of_section   dw 0;2
.TimeStump      dd 0
.Symbol_table_offset    dd 0;ntHeader
.Symbol_table_count dd 0
.Size_of_optional_header dw EntryPoint-optional_header
.Characteristics    dw 0x20 or IMAGE_FILE_RELOCS_STRIPPED or\
IMAGE_FILE_EXECUTABLE_IMAGE
;20h Handle >2Gb addresses
;-------------------------------------
optional_header:
.Magic_optional_header  dw IMAGE_NT_OPTIONAL_HDR64_MAGIC
.Linker_version_major_and_minor dw 9
.Size_of_code       dd 0
.Size_of_init_data  dd 0;xC0
.Size_of_uninit_data    dd 0
.entry_point        dd EntryPoint
.base_of_code       dd ntHeader
.image_base     dq IMAGE_BASE
.section_alignment  dd 4
.file_alignment     dd 4
.OS_version_major_minor dw 5,2
.image_version_major_minor dd 0
.subsystem_version_major_minor dw 5,2
.Win32_version      dd 0
.size_of_image      dd EndOfImage
.size_of_header     dd EntryPoint
.checksum       dd 0
.subsystem      dw IMAGE_SUBSYSTEM_WINDOWS_GUI
.DLL_flag       dw IMAGE_DLLCHARACTERISTICS_TERMINAL_SERVER_AWARE
.Stack_allocation   dq 0x100000
.Stack_commit       dq 0x1000
.Heap_allocation    dq 0x100000
.Heap_commit        dq 0x1000
.loader_flag        dd 0
.number_of_dirs     dd (EntryPoint-export_RVA_size)/8
export_RVA_size        dq 0
.import_RVA     dd 0
.import_size        dd 0

EntryPoint:
   enter 20h,0        ; space for 4 arguments + 16byte aligned stack
   mov rcx, name_ + IMAGE_BASE
   mov rdx, 1
   mov r8, 1
   mov r9, 2
   mov qword[rsp+68h-48h], 0
   call [file_]
   leave
   ret

Import_Table:
file_ dq 0x00007FF8F59A42F0
dq 0,0,0,0
name_ db 0x41,0x42,0x41,0x2E,0x74,0x78,0x74,0,0
end_import:
times 268-end_import db 0  ;filling up to 268 bytes
EndOfImage:
```

надо только переменную 'file_' поменять на свой адрес функции CreateFile2() из Kernel32. Она создаёт файл в папке с программой, правда пока кракозябра какая-то(надо с кодировкой наверное разбираться). Зато файл ещё меньше получается, да и остальное через LoadLibrary подгрузить можно.

Comment: Хорошо бы код еще)

Comment: @insolor, да пожалуйста, пользуйтесь на здоровье